# NSString Substring detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring, substring

I need help with replacing occurrences of string with another string. Occurrency that needs to be detected is actually some kind of function:

`%nx+a` or `%nx-a`

where `x` and `a` are some numbers.

So for example `%n10+2` or `%n54-11`.

I can't even use something like:
`NSRange startRange = [snippetString rangeOfString:@"%n"];`

because if I have two patterns within same string I'm checking I'll only get starting range of first one...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you need to do something with those two numbers. I think the best way is to use a regular expression to extract what you need in one go.

```
NSString * string = @"some %n5-3 string %n11+98";
NSError * regexError = nil;
NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"%n(\\d+)([+-])(\\d+)"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                          error:&regexError];
NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult * match in matches) {
    NSString * firstNumber = [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
    NSString * secondNumber = [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:3]];
    NSString * sign = [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
    // Do something useful with the numbers.
}
```

Of course if you just need to replace all the `%n` occurences with a constant string you can do that in one call:

```
NSString * result = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%n\\d+[+-]\\d+"
                                                      withString:@"here be dragons"
                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test this code. Minor bugs may be present.

Comment: Thats pretty cool. Actually I was pretty close using @Fogmeister solution but I haven't used NSRegularExpression before so I had some problems... didn't use those brackets but now it makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

For something like this you could use an `NSRegularExpression` and use the method `enumerateMatches:`.

Or you can create your own loop.

The first is the easiest once you have the correct pattern.

Something like...

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"%n" options:0 error:nil];

NSString *string = @"%n10+2*%n2";

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string
options:0
range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    // here you will get each instance of a match to the pattern
}];
```

You will have to check the docs for `NSRegularExpression` to learn how to do what work you need to do with this.

Docs... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -1):

Alter this code to match ur need

```
yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +" withString:@" "options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, yourString.length)];
```

Comment: What? I don't see how this will help in finding repeated instances of the searched for substring.